# Project uses older version of boost library

Tags: c++, boost, linker, shared-libraries

I am using arch and recently updated my system. Since then I can't link projects using the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/about/). I get this error message during linking:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable cloud_viewer
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.63.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../lib/libpcl_common.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.63.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../lib/libpcl_common.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_iostreams.so.1.63.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../lib/libpcl_io.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

I tried creating symlinks `libboost_xxxxx.so.1.63.0 -> libboost_xxxxx.so.1.64.0`

But while linking workes now, during execution the program crashes.
Should I just try to install the older `boot library` or is there a better solution?

Comment: You should install the older library, definitiely.

Comment: Another option is to assume that nothing you are currently using is depricated and re-compile the sources with 1.64.0.  If you get some compiler errors, update the affected sources and hope for the best.  This is what I would do if they were my sources.  If you're compiling someone else's sources, then I would elect to just install the old version.

Comment: Did you compile the point cloud library at some point prior to the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Recompile the PCL against current Boost and hope it still works (chances are relatively high)
2. Install the older version of boost alongside your current system version. I'm not sure how exactly to prevent the general (unversioned) symlink creation (you might not need to do anything special). An easy way to keep another version is to install it to e.g. /opt/boost-1.63 instead of /usr.

Both are equally food options,  provided the first one also works at all.

Comment: Just as a general question, should I install the old libboost version in the same directory as the current one, or should I install it in a different directory?

Comment: You'll need to put the headers in some other directory, but the libraries themselves should be versioned preventing name clashes. They might be automatically symlinked to unversioned names though, depends on the Boost build system. Make sure to use a proper PKGBUILD in this case and do not manually install anything to root. The alternative is to install the older version to /opt, which is by far the simplest option.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! If I can ask one little thing. I found the old version of the boost lib in the pacman cache andextracted it to `/usr/oldlib/boot`. But there are now only libraries, now headers. Are those the same as for the new version?

Comment: No the headers are also different (most of boost is also header-only). The arch packaged should be boost and boost-libs. Extracting both should give you the proper install. Note that I strongly suggest not putting this kind of thing in /usr, which should be managed by the package manager. Just put it in /opt.

Comment: You are right, I only installed the `boost-lib` package, but forgot about the `boost` package.